# firebase executing method twice

Tags: firebase

I have set up a firebase simple login and its all working within my angular project. However for soem reason when ever I call the functions I have set up containing the login and createUser methods, they are called twice?

The controller is set up as follows:

```
angular.module('webApp')
    .controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $window, $timeout) {
        var ref = new Firebase('https://sizzling-fire-4246.firebaseio.com/');
```

and both methods are placed within my function straight from the firebase example on their website

When I press register, it will create the user and authenticate it, and then it will run again and tell me the email is taken.

I have checked with and without the timeouts and it still happens.

```
$scope.login = function(){
            $scope.loginErrors = [];
            $scope.loginSuccess = '';
            var user = $scope.loginUser;

            if(user.email === ''){
                $scope.loginErrors.push('Please enter your email');
            }
            else if(user.password === ''){
                $scope.loginErrors.push('Please enter your password');
            } 
            else if(user.email === 'Admin'){
                $window.location.href = '/#/admin';
            } else {
                ref.authWithPassword({
                  email    : user.email,
                  password : user.password
                }, function(error, authData) {
                  if (error) {
                    switch(error.code) {
                        case 'INVALID_EMAIL':
                            $scope.loginShow = true;
                            $timeout( function(){ $scope.loginMessage = 'Please enter a valid email address'; }, 500);
                              break;
                         case 'INVALID_USER':
                            $scope.loginShow = true;
                            $timeout( function(){ $scope.loginMessage = 'Please enter a valid user address'; }, 500);
                              break;
                        case 'INVALID_PASSWORD':
                            $scope.loginShow = true;
                            $timeout( function(){ $scope.loginMessage = 'Please enter the correct password'; }, 500);
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log('error', error);
                            }
                    } else {

                        console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
                        $window.location.href = '/#/dashboard';

                    }
                });
            }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What method is being called twice? Where is the code that invokes it? Consider that, to help debug an error, we're going to need to have enough code to reproduce it. Could we copy/paste that into a browser and run it to see the issue? See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when developing and I had two browser tabs up running browser sync. Closed one and the problem went away.